# display corresponding fields in mongo in a list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my stored data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57080a7b01351177a4113f63"), "title" : "Data Scientist", "url" : "https://www.Pinterest.com/jobs/732?t=nu6xow", "timestamp" : "2016-04-08 19:46:03", "company" : "Pinterest", "state" : " CA", "todays_date" : "04/08/2016", "city_name" : "San+Francisco", "location" : "San Francisco, CA", "team" : "T0BT323QS", "search_word" : "Data+scientist"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57080a7b01351177a4113f64"), "title" : "Director of Analytics / Data Mining", "url" : "http://www.Pinterest.com/careers-position-data-mining-leader", "timestamp" : "2016-04-08 19:46:03", "company" : "Pinterest", "state" : " CA", "todays_date" : "04/08/2016", "city_name" : "San+Francisco", "location" : "Silicon Valley, CA", "team" : "T0BT323QS", "search_word" : "Data+scientist"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57080a7d01351177a4113f65"), "title" : "Senior Real World Data Scientist", "url" : "http://www.Pinterest.com/careers/detail/00443369/Senior-Real-World-Data-Scientist?src=JB-12568", "timestamp" : "2016-04-08 19:46:05", "company" : "Pinterest", "state" : " CA", "todays_date" : "04/08/2016", "city_name" : "San+Francisco", "location" : "South San Francisco, CA", "team" : "T0BT323QS", "search_word" : "Data+scientist"}
```

This is my query:

```
db.Books.aggregate([{$match:{"timestamp":{
       $gte: "2016-04-08 19:46:03", $lt: "2016-04-08 19:46:06"}}}
     ,{ "$group": {
        "_id": "$company",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "urls": {
            "$addToSet": "$url"
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 10 },
    { "$project": {
        "count": 1,
        "urls": { "$slice": ["$urls",0, 3] }
    }}
])
```

This is the output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Pinterest", 
    "urls" : [ 
        "https://www.Pinterest.com/jobs/732?t=nu6xow",
        "http://www.Pinterest.com/careers-position-data-mining-leader",
        "http://www.Pinterest.com/careers/detail/00443369/Senior-Real-World-Data-Scientist?src=JB-12568" 
    ] 
}
```

However, alongwith "url" I want it to display corresponding "title" and "location" field. Something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Pinterest", 
    "urls" : [ 
        [
            "https://www.Pinterest.com/jobs/732?t=nu6xow",
            "Data Scientist","San Francisco, CA"
        ],[
            "http://www.Pinterest.com/careers-position-data-mining-leader",
            "Director of Analytics / Data Mining","Silicon Valley, CA"
        ],[
            "http://www.Pinterest.com/careers/detail/00443369/Senior-Real-World-Data-Scientist?src=JB-12568",
            "Senior Real World Data Scientist",
            "South San Francisco, CA"
        ]
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the MongoDB 2.6 through 3.2 releases, you would need some help from `$map`:

```js
db.Books.aggregate([
   { "$match":{ 
       "timestamp":{
           "$gte": "2016-04-08 19:46:03", "$lt": "2016-04-08 19:46:06"
       }
   }},
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$company",
       "count": { "$sum": 1 },
       "urls": {
            "$push": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": [ "A", "B", "C" ],
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                      "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$$el", "A" ] },
                        "$url",
                        { "$cond": [
                          { "$eq": [ "$$el", "B" ] },
                          "$title",
                          "$location"
                        ]}
                      ]
                    }
                }
            }
       }
   }},
   { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
   { "$limit": 10 },
   { "$project": {
     "count": 1,
     "urls": { "$slice": ["$urls",0, 3] }
  }}
])
```

And that is how you would get each item notated as an array.

You probably really should be doing this though instead:

```js
db.Books.aggregate([
   { "$match":{ 
       "timestamp":{
           "$gte": "2016-04-08 19:46:03", "$lt": "2016-04-08 19:46:06"
       }
   }},
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$company",
       "count": { "$sum": 1 },
       "urls": {
            "$push": {
               "url": "$url",
               "title": "$title",
               "location": "$location"
            }
       }
   }},
   { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
   { "$limit": 10 },
   { "$project": {
     "count": 1,
     "urls": { "$slice": ["$urls",0, 3] }
  }}
])
```

Since it does actually identify the fields by key. But if for some reason you prefer the array format, then you can do it that way.

---

For `$addToSet` then just replace the `$push` with `$addToSet`, but if not **all** fields are unique, then `$group` on the `"url"` property first:

```js
db.Books.aggregate([
   { "$match":{ 
       "timestamp":{
           "$gte": "2016-04-08 19:46:03", "$lt": "2016-04-08 19:46:06"
       }
   }},
   { "$group": {
     "_id": { 
        "company": "$company",
        "url": "$url"
     },
     "title": { "$first": "$title" },
     "location": { "$first": "$location" },
     "count": { "$sum": 1 }
   }},
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id.company",
       "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
       "urls": {
            "$push": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": [ "A", "B", "C" ],
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                      "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$$el", "A" ] },
                        "$_id.url",
                        { "$cond": [
                          { "$eq": [ "$$el", "B" ] },
                          "$title",
                          "$location"
                        ]}
                      ]
                    }
                }
            }
       }
   }},
   { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
   { "$limit": 10 },
   { "$project": {
     "count": 1,
     "urls": { "$slice": ["$urls",0, 3] }
  }}
])
```

Comment: : Thanks for the answer, however "url" should be unique and I have updated it in my question. Sorry, I forgot to mention earlier, so it should be "$addToSet" instead of "$push". Also, your current answer gives me error. I am using 3.2. I have edited your answer  and pasted the error.

Comment: @dsl1990 Sorry, but it's one case still where you cannot directly notate an array, so use `$map` as was the alternate listing. As for `$addToSet`, it's either a direct transposition with `$push` or if the "title" and "location" are not the same for every "url" then you can actually "pre-group" with as shown in the last example. For future reference you cannot "edit" responses into other peoples posts. Leave a comment instead, or include in you **own** post.

Comment: Sorry for the edit, I will keep it in mind in future. The last answer is giving me error. Looks like curly bracket issue. If you could correct that query, it would be great. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @dsl1990 Actually it was "square"` brackets, and missing `]` inside expressions in `$cond`. Corrected. I learned something here about how the new array notation cannot be applied within `$push`. So a fair question all in all. The `$map` however ( which returns an array ) as an expression is deemed okay. Go figure!

Comment: There is a extra curly bracket here. I did not edit your answer as you instructed. You can edit it. 3 opening brackets and 4 closing brackets. { "$match":{ "timestamp":{  "$gte": "2016-04-08 19:46:03", "$lt": "2016-04-08 19:46:06"}}}},

Comment: @dsl1990 Actually **that** kind of edit is okay. It's just the "anotations" such as the error message which have a specific *"attempt to reply"* reject reason, and should be rejected on that basis. So leaving comments in the post should be a "comment" instead, but "corrections" are okay. But thanks!

Comment: @dsl1990 For the record, just opened a JIRA issue on this: [SERVER-23839](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23839)

Answer (score 1):

the way to get similar document is to $push document with selected filed to urls array

```
db.a1.aggregate([{$match:{"timestamp":{
       $gte: "2016-04-08 19:46:03", $lt: "2016-04-08 19:46:06"}}}
     ,{ "$group": {
        "_id": "$company",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "urls": {
            "$push": {url:"$url", title:"$title", location:"$location"}
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 10 },
    { "$project": {
        "count": 1,
        "urls": { "$slice": ["$urls",0, 3] }
    }}
])
```

then you will be able to get document shaped like this one:

```
   {
    "_id" : "Pinterest",
    "count" : 3,
    "urls" : [ 
        {
            "url" : "https://www.Pinterest.com/jobs/732?t=nu6xow",
            "title" : "Data Scientist",
            "location" : "San Francisco, CA"
        }, 
        {
            "url" : "http://www.Pinterest.com/careers-position-data-mining-leader",
            "title" : "Director of Analytics / Data Mining",
            "location" : "Silicon Valley, CA"
        }, 
        {
            "url" : "http://www.Pinterest.com/careers/detail/00443369/Senior-Real-World-Data-Scientist?src=JB-12568",
            "title" : "Senior Real World Data Scientist",
            "location" : "South San Francisco, CA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any questions welcome!

Have fun!

Comment: : Thanks for the answer, however "url" should be unique and I have updated it in my question. Sorry, I forgot to mention earlier, so it should be "$addToSet" instead of "$push".  If you could edit your answer that would be great.